# sqlite3 - Filtering out the very first and last record that have same identifier

Tags: sqlite

```
id,date,source,target,identifier
1,2020-10-10,internal,external,abc-123
2,2020-10-10,internal,internal,xyz-123
3,2020-10-11,external,external,abc-123
4,2020-10-12,external,external,abc-123
```

There are three entries for the same record (abc-123) and I would like to filter out the oldest and the newest record. For all the records, if there are duplicates then I would like to get the oldest and newest record.

I have no idea how to construct such a query. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to remove the oldest and newest, or keep both and remove everything else?  Can you add sample output to your question?

Comment: I want to SELECT only the oldest and newest and filter out the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use analytic functions here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY identifier) min_date,
              MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY identifier) max_date
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, date, source, target, identifier
FROM cte
WHERE date IN (min_date, max_date);
```

The CTE above adds to your table two new columns for the min and max date per each identifier.  The outer query then restricts to only records having those min or max dates.